Make citation bold when one of its authors belongs to a list
I am preparing an application for funding, and I'd like to highlight the citations in the main text when they are from authors belonging to the consortium.
I am already highlighting author names from different teams in the consortium using a redefined \DeclareNameFormat{author} macro with biblatex. Is it possible to additionally change the citation label in the same context?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,maxnames=99]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\IfStringInList[2]{\IfSubStr{,#2,}{,#1,}}
\newcommand{\mynameformat}{\namepartfamily%
    \addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni%
    \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\addspace\namepartprefix}%
    \ifdefvoid{\namepartsuffixi}{}{\namepartsuffixi}}

\newcommand{\makeauthorscolours}[4]{%
  \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \IfStringInList{\namepartfamily}{#1}%
    {\mkbibbold{\mynameformat}}%
    {%
      \IfStringInList{\namepartfamily}{#2}%
      {\mkbibbold{\textcolor{blue}{\mynameformat}}}%
      {%
        \IfStringInList{\namepartfamily}{#3}%
          {\mkbibbold{\textcolor{red}{\mynameformat}}}%
          {%
            \IfStringInList{\namepartfamily}{#4}%
            {\mkbibbold{\textcolor{brown}{\mynameformat}}}%
            {\mynameformat}%
          }%
      }%
    }%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {\ifmorenames{\addspace et al\andothersdelim}{}}%
  }%
}%

\makeauthorscolours{Her,Him,People}{Du,Sie,Mensch}{Moi,Gens,Potes,Collègues}{Amici}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Loftin80, 
  title  = {Subsonic Aircraft: Evolution and the Matching of Size to Performance},
  author = {Maj Her and Some Other and Laurence K. People and Aussi Moi},
  year   = {1980}
}
@book{Noone90,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Ghost H. Spirit},
  year = {1855}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I'd like this citation to appear in bold \autocite{Loftin80} but not this one \cite{Noone90}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Output without the desired feature:


A good solution here will depend on the citation style you intend to use. Could you tell us more about your bibliography and citation setup? Ideally in the form of a short, compilable exampled document that includes a couple of example .bib entries and reproduces what you have so far.

@moewe: MWE added, thanks.

Oh. numeric-comp is one of the more tricky styles here: It could in theory be that one of the "bold" references is compressed (e.g. "2" should be bold, but we cite "1-3"). So we need additional code to make sure that highlighted references are never dropped. I probably won't have time to look into this in the detail required for an answer in the next two days or so, but I will return later if no one else has posted an answer.

Well, I could very much understand that switching to plain numeric could be a better choice here.
